# .querySelectorAll() returning an empty nodelist React js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, intersection-observer

Hi I'm new here and I was trying to learn react js along with intersection observer api,
I was trying to get all elements with .cards class using `.querySelectorAll(".cards");`,
my problem is that it was returning an empty nodelist instead of a list of my elements.
I thought its on the initializing of the elements on my components so I tried putting defer attribute on my script and put it below the root elemen but it didnt work either.

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title> Intersection Obsever </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script defer type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
    <script defer src="/src/Intersection Observer/intersection-observer.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/src/Intersection Observer/Observer.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

App Component

```
import CardHolder from './Components/CardHolder'
import './App.css'

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <CardHolder/>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

CardHolder Component

```
import Cards from "./Cards";

function CardHolder() {
    return (
        <div className="cardHolder">
            <h1 style={{color: "lightblue"}}> Cards </h1>
            <Cards/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CardHolder;
```

Cards Component

```
function Cards() {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="cards"> Cards </div>
            <div className="cards"> Cards </div>
            <div className="cards"> Cards </div>
            <div className="cards"> Cards </div>
            <div className="cards"> Cards </div>
            <div className="cards"> Cards </div>
            <div className="cards"> Cards </div>
            <div className="cards"> Cards </div>
            <div className="cards"> Cards </div>
            <div className="cards"> Cards </div>
            <div className="cards"> Cards </div>
            <div className="cards"> Cards </div>
            <div className="cards"> Cards </div>
            <div className="cards"> Cards </div>
            <div className="cards"> Cards </div>
            <div className="cards"> Cards </div>
            <div className="cards"> Cards </div>
            <div className="cards"> Cards </div>
            <div className="cards"> Cards </div>
            <div className="cards"> Cards </div>
            <div className="cards"> Cards </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Cards;
```

Observer js

```
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
    entries.forEach(en => {
        if (en.isIntersecting) {
            en.target.classList.add("show");
        } else { en.target.classList.remove("show");} 
    })
}, {
    threshold: 0.5
})

const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".cards");
cards.forEach(card => {
    observer.observe(card);
})
```

I was trying get the cards elements and put it into the card variable so I can observe every each of them using forEach

Comment: When your Observer.js is executed, the cards are not even rendered in the dom, so your issue is normal. You've to wait for the first paint. There are too many ways to do that...